# hide a div and show new one in initial position

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have 2 div's side by side. What I want to do is hide/remove the left div and replace it with the right one which will move to the left and take the initial position of the right div.

I want this to be done when the **about** link is clicked.

HTML -

```
<div class="nav">
            <div class="column c1">
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="feed" class="feed" style="margin-top: 54px;">

            <div class="column c2">
                <p>
                    Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory
                    that provides you with up to date information on
                    current, and future work of creatives of colour
                    being showcased in the UK. C-oC aims to contribute to the
                    necessary exaltation of talented artists within the various
                    ethnic minorities within the UK.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
                </p>
            </div>

    <!-- Show on click -->

    <div class="feed-show" style="margin-top: 54px;">

            <div class="column c2">
                <p>
                    Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory
                    that provides you with up to date information on
                    current, and future work of creatives of colour
                    being showcased in the UK. C-oC aims to contribute to the
                    necessary exaltation of talented artists within the various
                    ethnic minorities within the UK.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
                </p>
            </div>


        </div>
```

CSS -

```
    .c1 {
    max-width: 24%;
}

.column {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: 585px;
}

/* feed */
.feed {
    width: 96%;
    left: 2%;
    margin-top: 75px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.c2 {
    max-width: 49%;
}

.feed-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top:2.5%;
}

.f-artist {
    padding-top: 1%;
}
```

The idea is to give the site a one-page style.

Hopefully this can be achieved with CSS only, however jQuery suggestions are more then welcome.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weXgWm?editors=1100)

Thanks!

Comment: You should at least try to do the jQuery code first. There are more than enough examples out there to get you started. And no, this can't be done with CSS alone.

Comment: If they're the same size div ("one-page" as you put it) then put them side-by-side in a div with overflow-x:hidden (which will then be twice the size of one-page) and animate margin-left from 0 to -pagewidth.

Answer (score 0):

You should try jquery .hide() function for you to hide your desired division. Your css seems to be okay because division are float in left.

```
$(document).ready(function){
    //about click
    $('.c1').on('click',function(){
        $('#feed').hide()

    })
}
```